# System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse array of objects

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

I am trying to parse below json using `System.Text.Json.JsonDocument`

```
[
    {
        "Name" : "Test 2",
        "NumberOfComponents" : 1,
        "IsActive" : true,
        "CreatedBy" : "bsharma"
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Test 2",
        "NumberOfComponents" : 1,
        "IsActive" : true,
        "CreatedBy" : "bsharma"
    }
]
```

The code to parse:

```
 using var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(inputStream, _jsonDocumentOptions);
```

The parsing fails with error:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message='[' is an invalid start of a property name. Expected a '"'. LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 4.
  Source=System.Text.Json
  StackTrace:
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8JsonSpan, Utf8JsonReader reader, MetadataDb& database, StackRowStack& stack)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 utf8Json, JsonReaderOptions readerOptions, Byte[] extraRentedBytes)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(Stream utf8Json, JsonDocumentOptions options)
```

The json input is being sent in via an http request. The error message indicates to put the array in a property in form `{ "values" : [ .. ] }`, which solves the problem. Is there a way to get a JsonDocument instance for the original json or the original json is invalid?

EDIT:
The json comes from serializing an array:

```
    var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        WriteIndented = true
    };

    var pocos = new Container[]
    {
        new Container { Name= "Test 2", NumberOfComponents = 2, IsActive = true ,CreatedBy = "bsharma" },
        new Container { Name= "Test 2", NumberOfComponents = 2, IsActive = true ,CreatedBy = "bsharma" }
    };
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(pocos, jsonOptions);
```

Comment: Your json string is invalid.How did you get the json?If you just hard encode the json,just change by yourself.

Comment: Corrected the json string. The json comes from serializing an array `Container[]`

Comment: Could you share how do you get the json?

Comment: @Rena, I have added the code which generates json.

Comment: If i just use `JsonDocument.Parse(json)`,it could not make such issue.What is your `inputStream`?

Comment: `inputStream` is the stream pointing to json.  `JsonDocument.Parse(Stream, JsonDocumentOptions)` method is being used.

Comment: I see that `JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString)` is working. Looks like something wrong with the stream being read.

Answer (score 13):

[Try the new System.Text.Json APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/) from .NET Blog show an example of this.

> ```
> [
>    {
>        "date": "2013-01-07T00:00:00Z",
>        "temp": 23,
>    },
>    {
>        "date": "2013-01-08T00:00:00Z",
>        "temp": 28,
>    },
>    {
>        "date": "2013-01-14T00:00:00Z",
>        "temp": 8,
>    },
> ]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(json, options))
> {
>    int sumOfAllTemperatures = 0;
>    int count = 0;
>
>    foreach (JsonElement element in document.RootElement.EnumerateArray())
>    {
>        DateTimeOffset date = element.GetProperty("date").GetDateTimeOffset();
>        (...)
> ```

Answer (score 6):

`.NET 6` has added a new namespace [System.Text.Json.Nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes?view=net-6.0) which allows access random access to Json values in a similar manner to Newtonsoft.Json `JArray` and `JObject`.

You can use [`JsonNode.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.parse?view=net-6.0) to parse Json from a stream (or string or JsonReader) to a [`JsonArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonarray?view=net-6.0).

```
// parse from stream, string, utf8JsonReader
JsonArray? array = JsonNode.Parse(stream)?.AsArray();

// access values
string name = array[0]["Name"].ToString();
int number = (int) item["NumberOfComponents"];

// or iterate
foreach (var item in array)
{
    string name = item["Name"].ToString();
    int componentCount = (int) item["NumberOfComponents"];
    bool isActive = (bool) item["IsActive"];

    Console.WriteLine($"Name:{name}, #comps:{componentCount}, Active:{isActive}");
}

// serialize
var jsonString = array.ToJsonString();

// deserialize to defined class
List<Item> items = array.Deserialize<List<Item>>();
```

The addition of `JsonObject`, `JsonArray` and `JsonNode` makes working with Json in System.Text.Json a little easier if you just want to quickly access or modify the Json.

Also see my answer to [Equivalent of JObject in System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65620060/equivalent-of-jobject-in-system-text-json/71018559#71018559) for details on `JsonObject`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about JsonNode.  I was using JsonDocument, but it is not very easy.

Answer (score 3):

There is no option in `System.Text.Json` or `Newtonsoft.Json` to `Deserialize` a `Json Array` without a Name, but you can change the `Json String` in runtime :

```
public class SampleList
{
    public List<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
}


public class Sample
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfComponents { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var _jsonDocumentOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();

    var inputStream = File.ReadAllText("json.txt");

    // Add Json Array name
    inputStream = inputStream.Replace(@"[", "\"Samples\":[");

    var sample = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SampleList>(inputStream, _jsonDocumentOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var values = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Container>>(json);
```

or

```
var values = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Container[]>(json);
```

So you have an array of values.

Answer (score 2):

Original JSON is invalid.

Check json syntax on https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Of course you may manually trim first/last curly brackets from json string and then parse rest as array, but this does not align with "JsonDocument instance for the original json" in your question.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, since the question at the end is: `Is there a way to get a JsonDocument instance for the original json or the original json is invalid?`, and this answer correctly points out that the json is in fact invalid.

Comment: Most likely the downvote is because per Dmitry's own link, his follow up sentence is incorrect. The grammar at that link indicates that json is an "element", where an "element" is "ws value ws" where ws is whitespace and value is any of "object", "array", "string", "number", or literals "true", "false", "null". I.e. the root of a json document need not be an object.